# asp.net Memory Mapped File To share memory across web app

Tags: asp.net, memory-mapped-files, static-variables

Hello we have 2 web app that have same static variables:

```
Public Static List<User>;
```

When the variable change in an app we need to change the same variable in the other app.

So the question is: can i use MemoryMappedFile instead of static variable, so i can update the variable in one shot?

There are some drowback in using MemoryMappedFile ?
Is MemoryMappedFile fast like static varibales?

Comment: To achieve what you want, you will be mapping parts of managed heap, which is something out of this world. Maybe, keep things in a database?

Comment: i want to use memory for performance reason